# How do I do this in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Ok I now have this

```
public IEnumerable<roomvu_User> GetLocationUsers(
   long LocationID, 
   DateTime StartDate, 
   DateTime EndDate, 
   int StartRows, 
   int MaximumRows)
{
    using ( DataClasses_RoomViewDataContext context = Context )
    {
        IEnumerable<roomvu_LocationMapping> Mappings = 
            ( from m in context.roomvu_LocationMappings
              where ( m.LocationID == LocationID 
                 && ( StartDate <= m.EndDate && m.StartDate <= EndDate ) )
              select m ).Skip( StartRows ).Take( MaximumRows );

        List<roomvu_User> Users = new List<roomvu_User>();

        foreach ( roomvu_LocationMapping Mapping in Mappings )
        {
            roomvu_User User = ( from u in context.roomvu_Users 
                                 where ( u.ID == Mapping.UserID ) 
                                 select u ).Single();
            Users.Add( User );
        }

        return Users;
    }
}
```

But I hate the foreach bit, there must be a way to do this in a single LINQ expression.....

Help

Answer (score 1):

```
from m in context.roomvu_LocationMappings
join u in context.roomvu_Users
on m.UserID equals u.ID
where (m.LocationID == LocationID 
          && (StartDate <= m.EndDate && m.StartDate <= EndDate))
select new { Mapping = m, User = u }
```

Will return a sequence of `a` with two properties, `.Mapping` and `.User`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the most expressive way to represent what you're asking for. However, I'm not sure if LINQ to SQL is smart enough to translate the `Single()` call on the results of the `GroupJoin()` (how the compiler translates `join ... into j`):

```
public IEnumerable<roomvu_User> GetLocationUsers(
   long LocationID, 
   DateTime StartDate, 
   DateTime EndDate, 
   int StartRows, 
   int MaximumRows)
{
    using ( DataClasses_RoomViewDataContext context = Context )
    {
        IQueryable<roomvu_LocationMapping> Mappings = 
            ( from m in context.roomvu_LocationMappings
              where ( m.LocationID == LocationID 
                 && ( StartDate <= m.EndDate && m.StartDate <= EndDate ) )
              select m ).Skip( StartRows ).Take( MaximumRows );

        IQueryable<roomvu_User> Users =
              from Mapping in Mappings
              join User in context.roomvu_Users
                on Mapping.UserID equals User.ID into j
              select j.Single();

        return Users.ToList(); // Force execution
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return 
   Mappings.ConvertAll<roomvu_User>(new Converter<roomvu_LocationMapping, roomvu_User>(a =>
    {
       return (from u in context.roomvu_Users where (u.ID == Mapping.UserID) select u).Single();
    }));
```

Above is using the ConvertAll linq extension on the `List<roomvu_LocationMapping> Mappings`
or

```
return (from m in Mappings
        let u = context.roomvu_Users.Single(u => u.ID == m.UserID)
        select u).ToList();
```

not 100% sure about the second, make sure it works first

Edit: cos of your edit!

I dont know ur db structure but if romvu_Users is related with foreign keys you should just be able to change the select to

select m.roomvu_Users ).Skip( StartRows ).Take( MaximumRows );

in your Linq2Sql query